# Creating Nested Directories

Tags: php

I'm making a directory with the script seen below. How would I go about creating two more directories immediately inside this directory?

```
<?php

  $dir = $_POST['dirname'];
  if( mkdir( "./store/".$dir."/" , 0777 ) )
    echo "Directory of ".$dosjename." has been created successfully...";
  } else {
    echo "Failed to create directory...";               
  }

?>
```

Comment: um? `mkdir('./store/'.$dir.'/firstdir'); mkdir('./store/'.$dir./seconddir');`

Comment: You really should not be using `0777` as it will open up to others on your host, always `0755` for folders & `0644` for files....

Comment: Thanks i'll keep that in my mind...But whil the 0755 change something with the reed and right premision ?

Comment: Whil it giwe to the folders rwx--??? premision becose i need that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this

```
mkdir("./store/".$dir."/" , 0777)
```

creates a new directory, then surely this

```
mkdir("./store/".$dir."/foo/" , 0777)
mkdir("./store/".$dir."/bar/" , 0777)
```

creates two new directories in it?

Comment: Thank you man i was litl bit confused ... Because of "if" staintment :)

Comment: The "if" is just giving you the info if the directory in fact was created (such things can fail, e.g. if the PHP user has not the respective rights to write there, or the directory already exists)

Comment: @Neven, if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as the answer to your question by clicking the green checkmark to the left

Comment: Another hint, if you want to make sure that your code is portable then instead of using a forward slash, you can use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR like this: mkdir('store' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'foo', 0777);

Also note that single quotation marks are faster to parse than double quotation marks because they do not check for variables inside the string.